How to write a type safe function that supplies default values for common fields in Union Type
I have a logic that assembles steps into a list of steps for a test run. I can supply any type of a step to that logic, but every step has some fields in common. Since it is very tedious to provide the common fields for sequences of steps that are hardcoded, I want to write a helper function that provides default values for the fields but cannot get it through the TS compiler currently.
Step types:
// The concrete step types are composed as union of the Step_Base_Information 
// and some context dependent properties. All possible step types are then grouped
// into the category type Load_Profile_Step with an intersection.

export type Step_Base_Information = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  marker_text?: string | undefined;
};

type Physical_Value_Object = {
  Value: number;
  Unit: string;
}

type Load_Machine_Control_Types_T = "mode_1" | "mode_2";

export type Control_Load_Machine_Step = {
  step_type_id: "control_load_machine";
  power: "on" | "off";
  target_speed?: Physical_Value_Object;
  target_current?: Physical_Value_Object;
  ramp_time: Physical_Value_Object;
  target_torque?: Physical_Value_Object;
  control_type: Load_Machine_Control_Types_T;
  target_machine?: 1 | 2;
} & Step_Base_Information;

export type Control_Power_Supply_Step = {
  step_type_id: "control_power_supply";
  power: "on" | "off";
  voltage: Physical_Value_Object;
  target_current: Physical_Value_Object;
  internal_resistance?: Physical_Value_Object;
  frequency?: Physical_Value_Object;
} & Step_Base_Information;

// ... and many more step types like this


export type Load_Profile_Step =
  | Control_Load_Machine_Step
  | Control_Power_Supply_Step
  // and all other possible step types here 
;


My generation code is currently:

function generate_id(): string {
  // generate an ID
   return "an ID";
}


function gen_step<T extends Load_Profile_Step>(
  step: Omit<T, "id" | "name"> & Partial<Pick<T, "id" | "name">>
): T {
  return {
    id: step.id ?? generate_id(),
    name: step.name ?? "",
    ...step,
  };
}

but the TS compiler complains about it with the error:
error TS2322: Type '{ id: string; name: string | T["name"]; } & Omit<T, "id" | "name"> & Partial<Pick<T, "id" | "name">>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: string; name: string | T["name"]; } & Omit<T, "id" | "name"> & Partial<Pick<T, "id" | "name">>'.

I don't know how to fix the error. From the pure JS perspective it should work but I want TypeScript to also be happy about it.
The code can also be found on a Playground.

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when we copy and paste it into our IDEs. Right now there are undeclared things like Physical_Value_Object that cause lots of errors, and you're not asking about that. It would help for you to replace any custom stuff with built in stuff (e.g., string) so that we can focus on the issue at hand. Like, maybe just this code as your [mre]? Then we can jump in and work on it further.
